# jQuery image gallery plugin that shows images in three sizes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

Well there are so many image gallery plugins for jQuery, I need one that can show the images in three sizes. A basic image gallery plugin usually displays all thumbnails and one large image. Clicking on the thumbnail brings the larger version of the chosen image into view. I want something after this stage: clicking the larger image should open-up an even larger version of the image -- in a modal overlay or something, ideally with prev/next buttons. I think this option is available in some existing plugin but I just cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plugin like [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html) or [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) to set up the first 2 levels... thumbnail and larger image... and you could override the functionality of clicking the image to make it display larger instead of going to the next image.

For a nice pop-up effect to enlarge the picture when clicking on it, you could use take a look at [this plugin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).

Just look at the source code and switch some things around. I'm sure with a little bit of playing around, you can achieve the functionality you're looking for. If not, post back and someone will be able to come up with a better answer.

I hope this helps.